# how can an irreducible markov chain be transient?

Tags: stochastic-processes

If it's irreudible, then you can "get to anywhere from anywhere." a transient state is one that eventually leaves and never returns. but doesn't this contradict the irreducibility premise that you can get to anywhere from anywhere?

Comment: There's no contradiction. For example, a non-symmetric random walk is both irreducible and transient.

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between "can go" and "will go".

For a Markov chain $(X_n)$ write $T_y:=\inf\{n\ge 1: X_n=y\}$ and $P^x$ for the law of $(X_n)$ started at $X_0=x$.

**Irreducible:** $P^x[T_y<\infty]>0$ for all $x,y$.

Suppose $(X_n)$ is irreducible. Then $(X_n)$ is

**Recurrent** if $P^x[T_x<\infty]=1$ for all $x$;

**Transient** if  $P^x[T_x<\infty]<1$ for all $x$.

Comment: Your definition of transience is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed now.